# Using conditions and rules to replace entries in a nested list

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement, rule, expression-test

I need to write a single rule that replaces any pair in the testlist with the entry {"Error"}  if the first element is negative or the second element is not an integer.

I've done:

```
rule = {a___, (n_ /; NegativeQ[n]) | (y_ /; FloatQ[y]), 
   b___} -> {a, {"Error"}, b}

testlist = {{1.0, 1}, {-2.1, 2}, {1.0, 3}, {2.0, 4.1}, {5.0, 5}, {6.0,6}, {7.0, 7}, {-1.0, 8.0}}

testlist //. rule

Out: {{1., 1}, {-2.1, 2}, {1., 3}, {2., 4.1}, {5., 5}, {6., 6}, {7., 7}, {-1., 8.}}
Out: {{1., 1}, {-2.1, 2}, {1., 3}, {2., 4.1}, {5., 5}, {6., 6}, {7., 7}, {-1., 8.}}
```

I'm really stuck on this and very new with Mathematica. I'll appreciate any help!!

Comment: `NegativeQ[]` does not exist, but `Negative[]` does. Similarly, there is a function named `InexactNumberQ[]` you could use instead of the non-existent `FloatQ[]`. Try these replacements and report back.

Answer (score 2):

Still stuck? The elements in the list have the general format {_ ,_ }  and you need to transform this to {"Error"} if some conditions are met. So the rule will look like:

```
 rule = {_,_}->{"Error"}
```

The above rule would transform all entries.

The first entry in the pair has the condition: a negative number. This requires a `PatternTest`, which uses a question mark followed by what is required, in this case Negative.

```
rule = {_?Negative,_}->{"Error"}
```

The second entry in the pair has the condition: not an Integer. A "not" signals the use of `Except` in the pattern. That is the pattern is satisfied as long as you don't have an Integer.

```
rule = {_?Negative, Except[_Integer]} -> {"Error"}
```

```
testlist = {{1.0, 1}, {-2.1, 2}, {1.0, 3}, {2.0, 4.1}, {5.0, 5}, {6.0,
     6}, {7.0, 7}, {-1.0, 8.0}};
rule = {_?Negative, Except[_Integer]} -> {"Error"};
testlist /. rule

(* {{1., 1}, {-2.1, 2}, {1., 3}, {2., 4.1}, {5., 5}, {6., 6}, {7., 7}, {"Error"}} *)
```

You may wish to experiment with other PatternTest, such as **_?Positive** or **_Real?Negative**, etc.